# Seting mosquitto broker to listen on two ports?

Tags: mosquitto

I am currently building a application in c# using the mosquitto broker for mqtt trafficking, I can get the application connect over tcp (port 1883) or over tls (port 8883).  This is done using the port settings the conf file however the program crashes on whichever port is set in the listener value, so only the default port works -- I don't know if I will allow the user to select tcp or tls, but I would like to have this working correctly.

EDIT:

```
# Config file for mosquitto
user mosquitto

port 8883

cafile /home/ubuntu/mosquitto-certs/ca/cacert.pem

certfile /home/ubuntu/mosquitto-certs/ca/requests/webservercert.pem

keyfile /home/ubuntu/mosquitto-certs/ca/requests/webserverkey.pem

tls_version tlsv1

listener 1883

persistence true

log_dest stderr

log_type error

log_type warning

log_type notice

log_type information

connection_messages true

log_timestamp true

auth_plugin /etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so

auth_opt_host localhost

auth_opt_port 3306

auth_opt_user ****

auth_opt_pass *****

auth_opt_backends mysql

auth_opt_dbname test

auth_opt_userquery SELECT pw FROM users WHERE username = '%s' LIMIT 1

auth_opt_superquery SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) FROM users WHERE username = '%s' AND super = 1

auth_opt_aclquery SELECT topic FROM acls WHERE username = '%s'

auth_opt_superusers S*
```

[image: Logging in over TLS]

Work fine if I login over TLS, however if I disconnect and try to login over TCP I get the following error:

*A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException' occurred in M2Mqtt.Net.dll
{"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}*

Same thing if I flip the port and listener values.

Code to disconnected:

```
if (_mqttClient != null && _mqttClient.IsConnected)
{
        _mqttClient.Disconnect();
        _mqttClient = null;

        SubscribeBtn.Enabled = false;
        UnSubBTN.Enabled = false;
        PublishBtn.Enabled = false;
        ConnectBtn.Enabled = true;
        UsernameTB.Enabled = true;
        PasswordTB.Enabled = true;

        DisplayBox.Items.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Can you share your config file as well as error log?

Comment: @kartben Hi, I have updated the question and added as much info as I can..

Comment: You don't need to specify the default "port 1883" so I would suggest you do simply the following:

user mosquitto
listener 8883
cafile /home/ubuntu/mosquitto-certs/ca/cacert.pem
certfile /home/ubuntu/mosquitto-certs/ca/requests/webservercert.pem
keyfile /home/ubuntu/mosquitto-certs/ca/requests/webserverkey.pem
tls_version tlsv1
persistence true
...

Please tell me if this is makes any difference

Comment: @kartben thanks for the reply however that didn't make any difference to application is still crashed when I try an un-secure login.

Comment: Even when you try to login as unsecure the first time you open your app (ie not after having tried secure first, possibly leaving a connection pending?). But my guess is your UI code may be buggy, trying to do secure no matter the contents of the checkbox. Have you double checked that?

Comment: Ya I tried un-secure login before checking secure and vice-versa after changing the listener to the other port (no port setting).. I don't think it is a socket issue the client can only connect one way at the time then must disconnect (which is why I added that method) -- if I set the listener to 8883 the client doesn't start the handshake process so it looks like the server isn't listening on 1883 by default.. of course if I set them both with the client in listener mode the connecting is started by refused.. (and again vice-versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got this to work by setting listener 1883 and listener 8883 with the config for SSL/TLS after the secure listener.

Thanks @ralight for the broker and at @kartben for the replies.

Answer (score 3):

I think this sounds like your client being at fault I'm afraid, it doesn't seem like a mosquitto problem. I would suggest checking your mosquitto setup using the mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub clients. You can use them for both plain TCP and the TLS connections, e.g.

```
mosquitto_sub -p 1883 -h <host> -t '$SYS/#' -u <username> -P <password>
```

Or for TLS:

```
mosquitto_sub -p 8883 -h <host> -t '$SYS/#' -u <username> -P <password> --cafile <ca certificate>
```

If these work, you'll need to look to your program for the problem.